# Converting javascript objects between redux store and application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, serialization, redux

I'm dealing with a hand full of javascript objects that i get from an external api-library. I want to store the incoming objects in my react application using redux.

These objects are es2015 classes that also come with two handy methods called `fromJSON` and `toJSON`. As i want my redux store to be serializable (as it should be) i need a way to translate them to plain objects (`toJSON` does that by giving me back a dict). In my application i need to use these Objects as they come from the API since i need the methods attached to them and the api-client also wants these specific objects.

Is this a common need as i can't find much about this online or am i totally going the wrong path? How would i implement such a transformation? I'm currently thinking about attaching the es2015 classes to my action and call `toJSON` in my reducers. I could then create specific selectors that catch the json from redux and convert them back to the classes using the `fromJSON` functionality (would i have to memoize them?). These selectors could then be used in `mapStateToProps` to map then finally to a prop.

Let me know what you think about this and how/if i could improve this process.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "es2015 classes"? are these plain objects serialized as JSON? 2. Regarding `mapStateToProps` - you would probably want to memoize. I suggest reading http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html

Comment: By es2015 classes i meean https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux says the state SHOULD be serializable. It should be so, because at some point you might need to store the state locally (via some form of localstorage). But this does not mean the state has to consist of plain objects.

For example, lot of projects use Immutable.js objects for their state. There is an overhead serializing Immutable.js objects. But it can be done using transit-immutable-js.

From what I understand this principal is similar to your question.

What I understand from your question is that (whatever you mean by ES2015 classes) are deserializable/serilizable by fromJSON and toJSON methods, which is all you need.

Thus you can use your "API" objects in state and serialize it only when you need to store it locally.

Comment: I should have said that i need serialisation. And yes, i went that way lastly. I serialize my objects in my reducers and use reselect to memoize the back-transformation to my initial object types.